# How to find the name of the bitmap file that was just taken using the camera

Tags: android

I wrote some code that take a picture and I want to find the name of the bitmap file that was just taken.

I know how to get the bitmap - but I dont want to get the bitmap - I just need the name of the file that was saved on the sd card.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    if (requestCode == 0) 
    {    
        // This is the file name that i need to find ... 
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
//define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera activity
//imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
mImageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
Intent photoFromCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
photoFromCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
startActivityForResult(photoFromCamera, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then when you get the result:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
    case CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera: "+ mImageUri);
            String path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageUri);
            Log.d(TAG, "Result image path from camera: "+path);

        }
        break;
```

The helper method:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    // can post image
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Did it throw an exception? or you just didn't get the value. Try getting a cursor over the image but pass null as the projection, then using DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString() check the columns to see where does android store the image

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileObserver over the Media or the directory where new photo would be stored.
I hope this helps!